# how to give same styling to multiple classes

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I know how to give same styling to multiple classes , we do use a comma between the class names . but what i can't understand what this below code is.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle { background-color: #333; }
```

Comment: I think this is possible using scss. A workaround would be to create another class for all elements where you want this style(An element can have multiple classes)

Comment: It will applied only for "navbar-inverse" box.. "navbar-toggle" it may have the parent class is "navbar-inverse"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space between parts of a CSS selector is called [`descendant combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator):

```
ancestorSelector descendantSelector { rules }
```

A CSS selector utilizing this is called **descendant selector**. Please note that any amount of whitespace works just like a single space.

whereas `>` indicates a parent-child relationship and is called [`child combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

```
parentSelector > childSelector { rules }
```

A CSS selector utilizing this is called **child selector**.

Look at this example:

```css
/* 
  this will affect any element whose classlist contains "b" 
  inside any element whose classlist contains "a",
  no matter how deeply nested it is 
*/
.a .b {
  color: blue;
}

/* 
  this will affect only elements whose classlist contains "b" 
  and which are direct children of any element whose classlist contains "a"
*/
.a > .b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    This is the direct child of <code>&ltdiv class="a"&gt</code>.
    <div class="b">
      This is <strong>not a direct child</strong> of <code>&ltdiv class="a"&gt</code>.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="b">
      <hr />
      Unaffected by <code>.a &gt .b</code>, but <code>.a .b</code> matches.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its hierarchy this will impact to `.navbar-toggle` class under `navbar-inverse`

Comment: so we are not styling multiple classes here, we are targeting navbar-toggle which is under navbar-inverse to have color #333

Comment: right. and if both class on same element then it will be like .navbar-toggle.navbar-inverse without space between.

Comment: why can't we use this .navbar-inverse>.navbar-toggle

Comment: yes you can use this > too but for that you have to understand css selector. you can find more info on this -- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp for all css selector.

Comment: Hope this will answer all your question related to css selector & when can we use them.

Answer (score 1):

This will give background color to the element with class name "navbar-toggle" which is inside an element with class name "navbar-inverse"

Answer (score 0):

`navbar-inverse` is the parent and `.navbar-toggle` is the child.

When you want to make a hierarchy of parent and child classes, you follow this approach. In the below code, see how the first `.navbar-toggle` has background while the second one does not.

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-toggle">
    This is the child
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-toggle">
    This wont be affected!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why can't we use this .navbar-inverse>.navbar-toggle

Comment: Ancestor and descendant, not parent and child. OP is correct in their understanding that `>` indicates parent and child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

.navbar-inverse > .navbar-toggle { /*This style applied only for first level child*/

}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle { /*This style applied for all the child*/

}

Answer (score -1):

It shows that we have two classes

`.navbar-inverse` and `.navbar-toggle`

`.navbar-toggle` is child of `.navbar-inverse`

and the css applied will be workable for only and only where `.navbar-toggle` as child of `.navbar-inverse` will be written in html.

Comment: why can't we use this .navbar-inverse>.navbar-toggle